# Payment processor, avoiding payments being rejected due to 'transaction is a duplicate'?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, eway

Are other people seeing the error message:

> Payment Processor Error message: 9003: It appears that this transaction is a duplicate. Have you already submitted the form once? If so there may have been a connection problem. Check your email for a receipt from eWAY. If you do not receive a receipt within 2 hours you can try your transaction again. If you continue to have problems please contact the site administrator.

We are using the Eway Payment processor and CiviCRM.

We had a donation and a membership submitted at the same time and we had the donation go through but not the membership. The membership seemed to fail regularly so I rebuilt the form with profiles and captcha. We are still getting this error.

I can see the error message in the code. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/eWAY.php. It looks as though it is checking for a unique invoice id. Is there a way to manage the way invoice id's are created that we are not managing correctly? Is it a race condition?

CiviCRM 4.7.17.

The http server logs (cleaned up) from this IP address are:

```
[06/Apr/2017:16:02:32   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  200 16030   https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1
[06/Apr/2017:16:05:07   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  200 15965   https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact
[06/Apr/2017:16:05:36   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  200 15947   https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact
[06/Apr/2017:16:06:05   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  302     https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact
[06/Apr/2017:16:06:34   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  302     https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact?_qf_Confirm_display=true&qfKey=d30c3a51b960fea81a73d70d656af1a9_8907
```

It is referring back to itself which I can't explain.

A working test (form 4 not form 1)

```
[07/Apr/2017:05:10:25   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  302     https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=4
[07/Apr/2017:05:10:59   +1000]  POST /civicrm/contribute/transact HTTP/1.1  302     https://www.colongwilderness.org.au/civicrm/contribute/transact?_qf_Confirm_display=true&qfKey=37ea51cf5a1e3f5197f136c5801cba2f_4643
```

The log does show that the contribution was being made on an old form that I had replaced.

This form only uses the inline options for donations and memberships. Thew new form uses price sets.

Old form configuration

[image]

With a membership section

[image]

Comment: Four details to add to this: The IP address(es) (from your webserver logs) that is/are the origin IP when the error message is generated - do they belong to the visitor, or eWay? Does that URL get hit once, twice, or more often? What is the invoice ID / contribution ID which CiviCRM thinks is duplicated? What is the end status of the contribution / membership?

Comment: For further debugging: the [location of this error message in `CRM_Core_Payment_eWay::doDirectPayment()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/eWAY.php#L263), and the [definition of `CRM_Core_Payment::checkDupe()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment.php#L1288) ... you might need to add some debug to these to understand what's happening.

Comment: I checked three sites which are using eWay, and none of them were exhibiting this behaviour. Another potential cause might be duplicate submissions, either due to javascript or users double-clicking the submit button. But that's just guesswork - debugging will find you facts. Good luck!

Comment: The person did find an old form. My theory is that there are donation amounts and a membership price set in the same form. I can't see 2x transactions in eway - they just declined it. Maybe they aggregate on their end. Of course we don't keep any log of the hits our server makes on eway.  I'll add the web-server trace to the question.

Comment: Yes I have just had same issue reported on a site that was upgraded to 4.7.x from 4.6.x. The Contribution page offers Donation (inc Other amount) and Membership (not via a Price Set) AND uses "Separate Membership Payment"

Comment: I confirmed the issue arose when page was set to "Separate Membership Payment" and did not occur when that setting was turned off.

Comment: Yes.  I've run it for a week now without that setting and not had a problem

Comment: may also relate to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been confirmed by @petednz and by testing without the 'Separate membership payment' option, that unsetting this option resolves the 'transaction is a duplicate' error.

In our case the membership types were moved out of the form into a price set.